# How to put all value of array in a variable?

Tags: php, arrays

how to put all value of array like this:

```
$array = array('0'=>'apple','1' => 'mango', '2' => 'orange');
```

to

```
$fruits = "apple,mango,orange";
```

please help me... :( thank's before :D

Comment: Please search before asking :) This is as simple as: `$fruits = implode(',', $array);`.

Comment: txh all for helping me... sorry i'm a newbie :)

Answer (score 1):

Try by implode:

```
<?php
$array = array('0'=>'apple','1' => 'mango', '2' => 'orange'); 
echo implode(",",$array);
?>
```